# React, connect-mongoose & Express session/user login

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, session, connect-mongo

I'm trying to get sessions to work with a React front-end and an express + connect-mongo using MongoStore back-end.

Handle Register Function

```
async function handleRegister(evt){

       //Prevent default form redirect.
       evt.preventDefault();

       //Create a new user objec to pass into axios
       const user = {
           username: username,
           password: password
       }

       //Send axios post request to nodeJS API.
       await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/register",user)
       .then((res) => {
      
       history.push({
           pathname: '/',
           state: res.data
       });
       })
       .catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });

       //Push react history back to index page.
      
   }
```

Handle Login function

```
const handleLogin = async (evt) => {
    //Prevent default form submission
    evt.preventDefault();

    const loginDetails = {
        username: username,
        password: password,
    }
    //send login request to api
    await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/login', loginDetails)
    .then((res) => {
        
    })
    .catch((err) => {

    })
}
```

I'm stuck on trying to figure out how to make the data be sent back to react after either of the above functions. In the register function I've sent back the `res.data` which contains the session. See blow route for express

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {

    //Destructure req.body.
    const {username,password} = req.body;

    //hash password.
    const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);

    //Create new user to store in mongodb.
    const newUser = {
        username: username,
        password: hashedPassword
    }

    //Create new user document
    await User.create(newUser, (err, newlyAddedUser) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            req.session.username = newlyAddedUser.username;
            console.log(req.session);
            res.send(req.session);
        }
    })
});
```

With the `console.log(req.session)` it outputs the cookie and the username I added in the session itself.

Should I make a user object on the react side and store the username and password inside?
Should I be passing back the session itself to the route with  `history.push({ pathname: '/',state: res.data});`
How can I verify that the session is valid for the user using connect-mongo?

Answer (score 1):

I spent 10 minutes trying to understand what is your goal. Didn't find.

But whatever you need to use a jsonwebtoken if you want to ***verify that the session is valid*** like you said

Enjoy https://jwt.io/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken

I wouldn't store the session in the History state API like you do.

```
       history.push({
           pathname: '/',
           state: res.data
       });
```

You better use a sessionStorage and/or localStorage. The name just talks by itself.

Give me one point please